# Is there a way to add data to an existing csv file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, csv, file, powershell-cmdlet

I am very new to PowerShell, I want to know if there is a way to write contents or data to an existing `csv` file that already has data? I have a `csv` file named **test.csv** and these are the contents within it:

**test.csv**

```
Id, Email
123, Joe
125, John
126, Will
```

I want to know if its possible to rewrite/manipulate the `csv` file to add contents in the **test.csv** file as below:

**test.csv**

```
Id, Email
123, Joe@email.com
125, John@email.com
126, Will@email.com
```

This is the logic I tried:

```
$A = Import-Csv -Path .\Test.csv -Header 'Id', 'Email'
for each( $list in $A){
    $A | Get-Member | Add-Name '@Email' | Add-Member Email
}
```

Comment: iterate thru the collection and _change the value_ of the target property. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your `for` loop, access the `Email` property of each row and append "@email.com". After that, export your array back to csv:

```bsh
$A = Import-Csv -Path .\Test.csv 
foreach ($row in $A) {
    $row.Email += "@email.com"
}
$A | Export-Csv -Path .\Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

After that, the content of your csv file looks like this:

> ```
> "Id","Email"
> "123","Joe@email.com"
> "125","John@email.com"
> "126","Will@email.com"
> ```